# SQL Using Variable Value

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a variable like below in python;

```
run_id=5654
```

When i execute the below code;

```
df=curs.execute("select* from [DATABASE] where RunId=run_id")
```

I got an error:

> DataError: ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'run_id' to
>   data type smallint. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Could you please help me about this? How can i proceed?

Comment: You need to learn how to pass a variable to your query as a parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are connecting to your SQL Server instance using `pyodbc`, you should use a prepared statement with `?` as the placeholder:

```
run_id = '5654'
df = curs.execute("SELECT * FROM [DATABASE] WHERE RunId = ?", (run_id,))
```

Comment: yeah you are right, but i got this error: ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=0 param-type=numpy.int64', 'HY105')

Comment: It appears that the `RunId` column is some sort of text.  Then you need to bind a string variable, q.v. my updated answer.